# Wrap linux filter in java

Tags: java, io, pipe

I want to write a JUnit test that assures that our self-implemented XML canonicalization works just like "xmllint --c14n".

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("xmllint", "--c14n", "-");
    Process p = pb.start();
```

How can I feed the process with a test file and get the output for comparison similar to unix pipes & filters?

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 7 you can use the [`ProcessBuilder.redirectInput(java.io.File)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput%28java.io.File%29) method:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( ... );
pb.redirectInput("/path/to/testFile.txt");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Using Java 6 you will need to do it yourself with I/O streams.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

FileInputStream testFile = ...
OutputStream processInput = p.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(testFile, processInput);

InputStream processOutput = p.getInputStream();
// Either parse this, or IOUtils.copy it to a file and do a diff of some kind.
```

Comment: This does not work: OutputStream processInput = p.getInputStream();

Comment: Oops, sorry I always mix those method names up. It should be `getOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` to the process's stdin.

Comment: Ah, so p.getOutputStream() is the input to the process while p.getInputStream is its output? that's confusing...